# PHP SQL Server Database Select

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three SQL Server databases on one SQL Server instance. Every time I do query to different databases, I have to select the database.

Is there a way to do query without database select. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can [use identifiers as object names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879.aspx).  This should work:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM database_name..table_name 
 WHERE id = 1
```

It's a variation of `database_name.schema_name.object_name`.  There are more examples in the link.

### Caveat

---

The user you use needs to have access to both the database(s) and table(s) involved.

Comment: but they need to share credentials

Comment: Thank you very much. Solves a lot of problems for me :)